# jQuery and load(). Unable to change inner HTML in loaded class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, load

I'm trying to change inner HTML in loaded div by this function:

`$("#container").load("site.php");`

In `site.php` I have `<div class="users_count">` and I would like to put some text inside it. I'm trying to use `$(".users_count").html("TEST")` but it can't be done since jQuery do not see `.users_count` class.

I've heared about jQuery `on()` and `live()` but it requires some event like `click, keyup etc...`

I need to put some text in this div without any event - just do it in my function without user action.

Comment: please post your complete code here

Comment: Next time please search before asking such a basic question. Similar questions have already been asked many times and we don't need even more duplicate questions.

Answer (score 14):

You could use the complete callback of **[`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** :

> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed.

```
$("#container").load("site.php", function() {
    $(".users_count").html("TEST")
});
```

Comment: Similar questions have already been asked many times (you can find some by searching "jquery access loaded element"). Instead of answering it, you should find a good duplicate target and close this question.

Answer (score 11):

`$.fn.load()` is async, you could use `complete` callback:

```
$("#container").load("site.php", function(){
  $(this).find('.users_count').html('TEST');
});
```

`$(this).find('.users_count')` isntead of just `$('.users_count')` because it is better to set relevant context, you wouldn't want in most cases target elements not descendant of loaded content, depending `selector` used. In your case it would change nothing but sometimes who knows...

Comment: Similar questions have already been asked many times (you can find some by searching "jquery access loaded element"). Instead of answering it, you should find a good duplicate target and close this question.

Comment: @Gothdo ya surely but e.g your proposed duplicate doesn't clearly address the question about targeting loaded content, and only it. But for sure a better dupe could be find.

Answer (score 8):

You want to do stuff when the loading is complete. This is done in the complete callback.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
  // Do your stuff here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I've got another solution that do not require `on()` on `live()` from jQuery.

When I do `$("#container").load("example.php");` in `example.php` right before `</body>` I put `<script type ="text/javascript" src="myFunctions.js"></script>` which contains all my functions I want to use on my classes in example.php.

Now my jQuery functions do not have problems with finding classes or id's since they're loaded with my `example.php`.

Comment: JavaScript is highly asynchronous. The sooner you understand this concept, the sooner you'll move away from _hacks_ like these.